# Delete similar patern keys from redis using JAVA

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am using jedis for redis connect in java.

I want to delete similar pattern keys from redis server using jedis.
e.g.
1. 1_pattern
2. 2_pattern
3. 3_pattern
4. 4_pattern
5. 5_pattern

We can use del(key), but it will delete only one key.

I want something like del("*_pattern")

Answer (score 1):

It should use regex in redis. In your code:

```
String keyPattern = "*"+"pattern";
// or String keyPattern = "*_"+"pattern";
Set<String> keyList = jedis.keys(keyPattern);
for(String key:keyList){
    jedis.del(key);
}
```

// free redis resource
I think above solution work well.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most efficient way is to reduce the redis calls.

```
        String keyPattern = "*"+"pattern";
        Set<String>  keys = redis.keys(keyPattern);
        if (null != keys && keys.size() > 0) {
            redis.del(keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the [`DEL key [key ...]`](http://redis.io/commands/del) command with the [`KEYS pattern`](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command to get what you want.

For example, you can do this with [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.java) like so (pseudocode):

```
// or use "?_pattern" 
jedis.del(jedis.keys("*_pattern"));
```

But be aware that this operation could take a long time since `KEYS` is `O(N)` where `N` is the number of keys in the database, `DEL` is `O(M)` where `M` is the number of keys, and for each key being deleted that is a list/set/etc, its `O(P)`, where `P` is the length of the list/set/etc.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23444123/667260).

In your case, it's a simple call to deleteKeys("*_pattern");